# A simple Java program I need help with

Tags: java

I had to do a Java program that said:

> Write a program in java to implement Inheritance. Your program should have the following structure
>
> 1. Create a Base class to hold two Integers and a method to Display them.
> 2. In the derived Class add another Integer and Display it.
> 3. Create a method in the same derived Class to add the three numbers.
> 4. Pass the values to the integers and Display the results.

and I'm not that good at Java, so I don't know if what I did was right or wrong or what! And I think I didn't understand what was wanted quite well. Here is what I came up with:

```
public class firstclass {
    int a=5;
    int b=6;

    public void Display (){
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class secondclass extends firstclass {
    int z=0;

    public void Displaysecond (){
        System.out.println(z);
    }

    public void add (){
        z=a+b;
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class mainOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        firstclass call = new firstclass();
        secondclass call2 = new secondclass();

        call.Display();
        call2.Displaysecond();
        call2.add();
    }
}
```

It runs without any problems but I get "11" for the "System.out.println(a+b);" while a = 5 and b = 6.
Am I going about this correctly?

Comment: Isn't 5 + 6 = 11?

Comment: @Ziyao Pretty sure OP wants 5 + 6 = 56

Comment: @Ziyao Wei maybe he wants "5" + "6" = "56"

Comment: Well OP just brought a new kind of '+' to me:)

Comment: The + seems to be acting as concatenation. I suppose that the compiler is casting the first object to a String (well, technically calling String.valueOf()) and then applying the + operator, which will cause concatenation instead of addition. The solution? Enclosure in parentheses. `System.out.println((a + b));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems. As Grammin mentioned, your add function is not what your teacher wanted. Your teacher wanted you to a, b, and z. So

```
public void add(){
    int sum = a + b + z;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `void add()` `int add()` and return `sum`.

Secondly, you are not following Java convention. Your variables need to be more inappropriately named, your classes need to start with uppercase and your methods need to start with lowercase.

Perhaps you should name your classes FirstClass, SecondClass, and MainClass?

Your methods: display(), displaySecond(), and add()

Your variables: a,b,c or num1, num2, num3. (for consistency)

Also, call.display() should yield the same result as call2.display() because SecondClass is a subclass of FirstClass. Read [this](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-inheritance) for a better understanding of inheritance.

A side note: you should add your numbers in parentheses () for clarification and safety if you're doing some sort of in-line math. For example

```
public void display(){
    System.out.println((a + b));
}
```

instead of

```
public void display(){
    System.out.println(a+b);
}
```

Comment: great tips, I really loved them and made a not of them, thanks

Comment: The double set of parentheses is unnecessary.

Comment: Are you sure? I know I've had issues with that in the past. I think if you have any quote marks, you do need the nested parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks good except:

```
3. Create a method in the same derived Class to add the three numbers.

public void add ()
{
    z=a+b;
    System.out.println(z);
}
```

That method adds a and b but then puts it in z.  And it doesn't return anything so it should be something like:

```
public int add ()
{
    return a+b+z;
}
```

Then in the main you should have something like:

```
System.out.println(call2.add());
```

Comment: Thanks @Grammin I totally forgot that, rally thanks man, but about the "System.out.println(a+b)" why do I get 11 ? sholdent I get 5 6 ?

Comment: System.out.println(a+b) - you will get 11 because the a+b is actually evaluated as math operation. If you want to get 5 6 then you will do something like System.out.println(a + " " + b). In this case, the + sign is treated as string concat